# Bytecode injection in android Junit test cases

Tags: android, bytecode, dalvik, code-injection

I have written a small java agent that does bytecode injection at the time of class loading and it works fine on a standalone Java application by adding vm argument -javaagent path-to-agent-jar.

My requirement is to apply same java agent for instrumenting android app code.
I have to do some bytecode injection in android application while testing the code through Junit.

My question is, does the instrumentation mechanism works the same way in dalvik vm as it works on normal java vm's?

If yes, then i wonder why it is not working in my Junit test cases.Thing to note here that my test class extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 from android Junit framework.

If no, what is the alternative by which i can achieve this? How do i inject code in dex file at runtime?

Comment: The Dalvik VM does not execute Java bytecode, and includes no mechanism for converting it to Dalvik bytecode (only the "dx" tool does that), so what you are doing isn't going to work.  The Dalvik VM does not currently provide a way to modify loaded bytecode.

Comment: What about using aspectj here? But as far as i know it also uses bytecode injection,hence i doubt if that would work. What i actually want is below process 1) Let javac compile the .java to .class file. 2) Let aspectj apply its advices and generate modified .class files. 3) Let dx tool pick modified .class files.

Comment: Anything you can do to the class files on the host side before "dx" runs should work.  I've successfully used a test coverage tool in the past.  The trouble is doing it on the device.

Comment: Yeah I agree to your point. I am trying to apply aspectj. Will keep posted if it gets successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully accomplished the requirement by using Aspectj.
If anyone ends up with similar problem, you can follow below wonderful blog that helped me.

https://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2011/07/18/aspect-oriented-android-development-tool-integration/

Answer (score 0):

No,

javaagent is technology introduced in Oracle JVM 1.5. It is not present in dalvik.

But instead you could change instrumentation to offline, try ASM/ASMDEX (http://asm.ow2.org / http://asm.ow2.org/asmdex-index.html).